# How can I change ASP.Net Identity 2 on SQL Server to create a newSequentialId Primary Key?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I have an ASP.NET Identity 2 implementation (no user data yet just base tables) that I have with a userId of type UNIQUEIDENTIFIER.

The application is a code first and I am using EF6.

Here's the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] (
    [Id]                   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [FirstName]            NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [LastName]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Email]                NVARCHAR (256) NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed]       BIT            NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] BIT            NOT NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled]     BIT            NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEndDateUtc]    DATETIME       NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled]       BIT            NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [UserName]             NVARCHAR (256) NOT NULL,
    [SubjectId]            INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [SubjectIds]           VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [OrganizationId]       INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    [OrganizationIds]      VARCHAR (50)   NULL,
    [RoleId]               INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);


GO
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [UserNameIndex]
    ON [dbo].[AspNetUsers]([UserName] ASC);
```

I understand that normal the GUID create is a normal GUID.

Can someone tell me how I can make this create a newSequential GUID?

**Please note**

I am looking for the correct way to do this specifically with ASP.Net Identity 2. In particular I would like to know if any changes are needed to the Identity 2 UserManager etc.

Comment: I didn't think it was possible b/c Identity could not be changed to create Sequential Guids, b/c Guid does not implement IConvertible. With use of Fluent API, I tuned Code-First EF to add `DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [Id]`. I may have left out steps in my explanation, but I was able to build and run the app, successfully registering / creating a user.

Comment: Having gone through it, I don't recommend it. It's not the amount of work, b/c between my guidlines, build errors, and intellisense, VS will take you through it. I suspect this is wasted work. Unless you have 10,000+ users, this optimization does not help. If you do end up with very high user base, performance  would be better with `int` for PK and an added `GUID` field to pass to browser. Also, sequential GUID's are not supported in many DB's (including Azure) because they pose security risks of revealing Mac address or users being able to guess GUID increments.

Comment: Alan, have you tried to implement my solution?

Answer (score 3):

I was finally able to build the project and run it. A `newsequentialid()` is assigned to the ID field after creation using Fluent API:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>().HasKey(x => new
        {
            x.RoleId,
            x.UserId
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>().HasKey(x => new
        {
            x.UserId,
            x.ProviderKey,
            x.LoginProvider
        });
    }
```

The result was SQL table that scripted as:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetUsers]    Script Date: 4/11/2015 3:40:51 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [PasswordHash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SecurityStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEndDateUtc] [datetime] NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ADD  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [Id]
GO
```

Had to change the other Entity Types:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole,
    CustomUserClaim>
{


    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public override Guid Id { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, Guid> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid> { }
public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid> { }
public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<Guid> { }

public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<Guid, CustomUserRole>
{
    public CustomRole() { }
    public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
}

public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, Guid,
    CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public CustomUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<CustomRole, Guid, CustomUserRole>
{
    public CustomRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole,
    Guid, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
```

In the Startup.Auth.cs, I changed

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator
                    .OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, Guid>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) =>
                            user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                        getUserIdCallback: (id) => new Guid(id.GetUserId()))
            }
        });            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
```

In the IdentityConfig.cs, I changed altered the ApplicationUserManager

Here:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, Guid>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, Guid> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(
            new CustomUserStore(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        // Configure validation logic for usernames             manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)

        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser, Guid>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
```

And

```
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Phone Code", new PhoneNumberTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, Guid>
        {
            MessageFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("Email Code", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, Guid>
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });
        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser, Guid>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
        return manager;
    }
}

// Configure the application sign-in manager which is used in this application.
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, Guid>
```

In ManageController.cs, I added

```
public class ManageController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private Guid userGuidId;

    public ManageController()
    {
        userGuidId= new Guid(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    }
```

Replacing `userGuidId` instead everywhere that I saw  `userId`

I had to use a `ToString()` here:

```
BrowserRemembered = await AuthenticationManager.TwoFactorBrowserRememberedAsync(userGuidId.ToString())
```

In Account Controller, I seem to have only changed

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ConfirmEmail(string userId, string code)
    {
        Guid GuidUserId = new Guid(userId);
        if (userId == null || code == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        var result = await UserManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(GuidUserId, code);
        return View(result.Succeeded ? "ConfirmEmail" : "Error");
    }
```

Comment: What part of this makes it sequential?

Comment: @Stilgar, the fluent api identity assignment was cropped (cut and paste)

Comment: @DaveAlperovich - See my comment above. It appears that the value is created in the C# code and not the database.

Comment: @Alan, you are correct. What I gave you was the first part. As I played with implementation, I realized I had to implement adjustments to UserManager and other classes down the pipeline. I followed further down the rabbit hole making other components work with GUID class but could not complete the task yet. I'll let you know if I succeed.

Answer (score 1):

First create non-generic version of the "IdentityUser" based classes...

```
public class AppUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid> { }
public class AppUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<Guid> { }
public class AppUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid> { }
```

...then the same for `IdentityRole` and `UserStore` and `UserManager...

```
public class AppRole : IdentityRole<Guid, AppUserRole> 
{ 
}

public class AppUserStore : UserStore<AppUser, AppRole, Guid, AppUserLogin, AppUserRole, AppUserClaim>
{
    public AppUserStore(DbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class AppUserManager : UserManager<AppUser, Guid>
{
    public AppUserManager(IUserStore<AppUser, Guid> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }
}
```

... and finally the `IdentityDbContext`...

```
public class AppIdentityContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUser, AppRole, Guid, AppUserLogin, AppUserRole, AppUserClaim>
{
    public AppIdentityContext()
        : base("name=AspNetIdentity")
    {
    }
}
```

Throughout all these new classes you will notice that the base classes use the generic version of the Identity classes and we are using the `AppUserClaim`, `AppUserLogin`, `AppUserRole` and `AppRole` in place of the Identity counterparts.

For the user we create a class named `AppUser` that will derive from `IdentityUser`:

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser<Guid, AppUserLogin, AppUserRole, AppUserClaim>
{
    [DllImport("rpcrt4.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int UuidCreateSequential(out Guid guid);

    private Guid _id;

    public AppUser()
    {
        UuidCreateSequential(out _id);
    }        

    /// <summary>
    /// User ID (Primary Key)
    /// </summary>
    public override Guid Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
}
```

In the constructor we use the `UuidCreateSequential` function to create a new ID and return that through the `Id` property. I wanted to setup the `Id` column in the database to use `newsequentialid()` as a default value and use that instead of a `DllImport`, but I've not worked that out yet.

To use in an controller action:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ActionName()
{
    AppIdentityContext dbContext = new AppIdentityContext();
    AppUserStore store = new AppUserStore(dbContext);
    AppUserManager manager = new AppUserManager(store);
    AppUser user = new AppUser { UserName = "<name>", Email = "<email>" };

    await manager.CreateAsync(user);

    return this.View();
}
```

A few things to note:

1. If you are using an existing database, i.e. one created with an SQL script and where the `Id` column in `AspNetUsers` is `nvarchar`, then you will need to change the following columns to a `uniqueidentifier`:

   - AspNetUsers.Id
   - AspNetRoles.Id
   - AspNetUserRoles.UserId
   - AspNetUserRoles.RoleId
2. Using the `GetUserId` extension method on the `IIdentity` interface within you ASP.NET MVC controllers, i.e. `this.User.Identity.GetUserId()`, will return a `string` so you will have to use the following when converting the return value to a string:

   `new Guid(this.User.Identity.GetUserId())`

   There is a generic version of this method, but underneath it uses `Convert.ChangeType` and that requires the value being passed in implements `IConvertable` and `Guid` does not.

I have not been able to fully test this, but hopefully it will provide a useful base if it doesn't fully meet your needs.

**UPDATE #1**: These are the steps I went through:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC application with No Authentication
2. Add the following NuGet packages

   - EntityFramework
   - Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core
   - Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
3. Add all the code samples to a file named `Identity.cs` in the `App_Start` folder

   **NOTE: Exclude the controller action sample..this will be done in step #6**
4. Remove all the Entity Framework parts from the `web.config`
5. Add a new connection string to `web.config` named `AspNetIdentity`
6. Add the controller action sample to the `Index` action on the `HomeController` and replace the `<name>` and `<email>` parts
7. Add a new, empty, database named `AspNetIdentity` to your SQL Server
8. Run the application

If you use the ASP.NET MVC template that has the *Individual User Accounts* authentication option selected, then there will be a few errors that will have to be fixed. These are mostly centred around changing references to the `IdentityUser*` classes to the new `AppUser*` based classes and replace calls to `User.Identity.GetUserId()` to use the code sample provided in step #2 in my original answer.

Comment: I find your post very interesting. Went through the same steps, but was not able to get it to compile. Have you had success building your implementatuion?

Comment: This approach seems to fall short. If the OP is able to implement your approach and build it, you still have not implemented a way for Identity to query for last User-Id and create next in the Sequence. Identity does not have an implementation for generating GUIDs, let alone Sequential GUID's.

Comment: This is done in the 'AppUser' class where 'Id' is overridden and 'UuidCreateSequential' is called in the constructor.

Comment: Would you change the DB type to Seq GUID this way?

Comment: Assigning a sequential ID in code using `UuidCreateSequential` is no different than using the SQL Server function `newsequentialid` as the SQL Server function `newsequentialid` is simply a wrapper around `UuidCreateSequential`.

Comment: I see. Then it may be a good approach. My only concern is, does Identity respect it. I had a hell of a time getting Identity to respect my changes directly to the table. I finally got Identity to work right using Fluent API to add `DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [Id]` after creation.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me to make *Roles* and *Users* Id fields of type Guid have `newsequentialid()` in Default Value or Binding:

1. Delete ***.cs** files in **Migrations** folder in Visual Studio
2. Drop table **__MigrationHistory** and all **AspNet*** tables in database
3. Add the following code to **ApplicationDbContext** class:

   ```
   protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
       modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
       modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().Property(t => t.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
   }
   ```
4. Run `Add-Migration Initial` in Visual Studio Package Manager Console
5. Run `Update-Database` in Visual Studio Package Manager Console

Warning: this will delete all users in roles from your database